# Unitary matrix commute with function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, operator-theory, tensors

I'm wondering in which cases the following identity is satisfied :
$$
f\left(UXU^T\right) = Uf\left(X\right)U^T
$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a square matrix, $U$ is any permutation matrix and $ f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

I already know of two cases :

1. $f$ can be expressed as a matrix Taylor series (in this case $U$ could be any unitary matrix)
2. $f$ is an element-wise function

Are these the general cases?

**Bonus :**

Is there an extension of the preceding identity to tensors $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n^m}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^{n^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^m}$. I am not sure what form the product and the operator $U$ would take in that case.

Comment: Other examples: (1) $f$ is an entrywise odd function and $U=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$, (2) $f$ is any function and $U=I$.

Comment: Since this question has not received much attention, you might want to change this to the context of your/others' research and ask if in that situation, with $U,f$ having certain properties does this result hold : because even if $f$ is somewhat irregular, then for special $X,U$ this could work.

Comment: $U$ is **an** unitary matrix or **arbitrary** unitary matrix? Is $U$ fixed?

Comment: I made the question a bit more precise : $U$ is any permutation matrix and $X$ is any square matrix. Both are fixed. I'll ask a different version of the question if it does not find an answer...

Comment: Much better! The answer below is brilliant.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a bit of relevant literature:

- [Deep Sets](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6931-deep-sets) (NIPS 2017) classifies all **linear functions** $\mathbb R^{n\times k} \to \mathbb R^{n\times l}$ that are permutation invariant / equivariant across the first axis.
- [On Universal Equivariant Set Networks](https://openreview.net/forum?id=HkxTwkrKDB)  (ICLR 2020) deals with the case of finding all **homogeneous polynomial functions** $\mathbb R^{n\times k} \to \mathbb R^{n\times l}$ that are permutation equivariant across the first axis.
- [Invariant and Equivariant Graph Networks](https://openreview.net/forum?id=Syx72jC9tm) (ICLR 2019) deals with the case of finding **linear functions** $\mathbb R^{n^k} \to \mathbb R^{n^k}$ that are permutation invariant / equivariant across all $k$ axes

Especially, the 3rd paper gives as an example the case of **linear function** $\mathbb R^{n^2}\to\mathbb R^{n^2}$ that are permutation equivariant across each axis, i.e. $f(P^T X P)=P^T f(X) P$, which is precisely your problem. They show that the space of such linear functions is $15$-dimensional, **independent of $n$ (!)**.

One can combine papers 2 and 3 to find all **homogeneous polynomial functions** $\mathbb R^{n^k}\to\mathbb R^{n^k}$ that are permutation equivariant across all $k$ axes.